# determining bottle necks in a linux server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, web-server

I have a quad core cpu with 4gb ram. I am running a VMware image of Ubuntu which I use as a web server for development/testing. I assigned this image 1gb ram and 2 cpus.

While it hosted my web portfolio just fine, I installed a number of CMSs  (joomla, drupal, wordpress) which take up to 30s for it to fully load.

What options are there in determining why it is running so slow?

I can post the .vmx file or detailed computer specs if needed.

Comment: "which take up to 30s for it to fully load." Can you elaborate - do you mean per page? Or do you mean for the whole server to boot? Or just the webserver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many reasons for this. Your first place to look would be anything I/O (disk) related as this is the slowest component of any system. If you run `top` when accessing one of the sites, and you observe that the value for `%wa` is consistently high (50%+ for a 2 CPU system), it's likely you're saturating your disks. You can run `vmstat 1` as well which will give you a better breakdown of what your system is doing. The `wa` value (usually the second last column under the `cpu` heading) is the same as the one in `top`. You could be out of RAM and therefore swapping, or your database(s) could be hitting the disks too often. In this case, I recommend increasing the RAM on the VM.

Second place to look is CPU contention. If yous CPU is constantly high between the user and system values (`us` and `sy` values in vmstat), you likely need more CPUs on the system.

I/O and CPU contention are typically the causes of poor performance. As you can tell from this answer, there's no simple solution. Between `top`, `vmstat` and even `iostat`, you should be able to pinpoint what your system is doing.